# I haven't waited vs I haven't been waiting

Tags: difference, present-perfect, present-perfect-progressive

In the following text:

> A: I'm sorry I'm late.
>
> B: That's OK. I _______________ long.

I answered

> haven't waited

but the correct answer is

> haven't been waiting

Could you explain the difference between the two?

English Grammar in Use by Raymond Murphy  Additional exercises 14-7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny, I just gave this explanation to another user.

*You're problem isn't English. Your problem is that you failed to give the answer expected by the book.*

There are many grammatically correct ways to fill in that blank. For example:

- I haven't been waiting long.
- I haven't waited long.
- I wasn't waiting long.
- I didn't wait long.
- I wasn't standing here reading a book for very long.

But only one of those examples *was appropriate for your exercises.* At a guess, the book was testing your knowledge of the Present Perfect Continuous tense — but that wasn't what you used.

Remember, it's not enough to be grammatically correct, you must also be *contextually correct.* Flip a page or two back in the book and read again what was being taught.

Cheers, and thanks for asking!

BTW: The difference between the two is that the answer the book wanted implies the respondent is *still waiting* when asked the question. The answer you gave implies that the waiting ended sometime before the question was asked. It's a very small difference, but important!